# show background mg from directory in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, directory, background-image

i want to show background image in mvc from directory.here is my code

```
background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/UploadedFiles/" + item)')"
```

Comment: `background-image:url` you putting in `cshtml` file or something other file like in `CSS` file?

Comment: @jishansiddique in my view cshtml file.

Comment: In which portion are you adding this code? there are many way to use that item in `.cshtml` file.  what is the value `item` variable? of please describe your code briefly

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to save the 'item' with its background image link. Then you can directly use it through:

```
background-image:url('@Url.Content(item.picture)');
```

Comment: any other suggestion?